# Objective C pointer to pointer - how to distinguish passing nil vs not initialized variable set to nil

Tags: objective-c, pointers

I have a method which accepts pointer to pointer param:

```
+(void)someMethod:(NSString*_Nullable*_Nullable)parsed;
```

Now, if i call this method and pass "nil" as parameter, and then i do the dereference inside of method like:

```
*parsed = soemthing;
```

I get crash BAD Access. Now question is, how to construct condition to distinguish passing "nil" vs passing not initilized variable like:

```
NSString* s; // this is technically nil too, but dereference works and doesn't crash
[someObj someMethod:&s];
```

to prevent the crash mentioned in first case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is relatively simple, you should never pass an uninitialized variable.  Consider doing this:

```
NSString *s = nil;
[someObj someMethod:&s];
```

Note the &s as you have declared someMethod to require a NSString **.  By doing &s the parsed will always be defined, as the variable is obviously stored somewhere in memory. Its value, stored at *parsed will have been initialized to nil.  You should then be able to do things like:

```
+(void)someMethod:(NSString* _Nullable *_Nullable)parsed {
    if( NULL != parsed ) {
        if( nil == *parsed ) {
            *parsed = @"Our variable *s will now be set!";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for reply. Now i see that the solution is maybe easier than i thought. if (parsed) condition should be enough to check the problem, as parsed is an address of that pointer in the memory and the address is not null in case of passing pointer (even) to not initialized variable.

Comment: Strictly, the first test should be for `NULL` rather than `nil`. The latter is only for object types. The second pointer is not itself an object.

Comment: @JoshCaswell thanks, I updated the code to reflect this.  Although I have yet to see a platform where NULL and nil are not both represented by numerical value 0, you are correct in that nil should be used for object pointers and NULL for memory pointers.